# Move Pagination outside of slides-container wrapper in jquery SuperSlides

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am currently using jQuery Superslides and would like to move the pagination outside of the wrapper div. Right now the pagination sits on top of my images and I would like to move the pagination below. I've tried insertAfer the container, which works but it throws of the pagination slide order off.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? I am assuming the superslide.js file has to be tweaked...

Any suggestions or if anyone has ran into the problem and has a solution that would be great!

Default Output:

```
<div id="slides" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 594px;">
 <div class="slides-control" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 4995px; left: -1665px;">
 <nav class="slides-pagination">
  <a class="current" href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
 </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just output the custom pagination HTML yourself like this:

```
<nav class="slides-pagination">
    <a class="current" href="#1">1</a>
    <a href="#2">2</a>
    <a href="#3">3</a>
</nav>
```

Then disable the auto pagination feature:

```
$('#slides').superslides({
    pagination: false
});
```

And since they attach the `.current` class only to the autogenerated menu, you need to replicate this function using the `animated.slides` event like this:

```
$('#slides').superslides({
    pagination: false
}).on('animated.slides', function() { 
    var current_index = $(this).superslides('current');
    $('.slides-pagination a').removeClass('current');
    $('.slides-pagination a').eq(current_index).addClass('current');
});
```